# C++ default constructors absence and I cannot compile

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I have this very simple class

```
class myclass {

public:
    int id;
    double x, y, z;

    myclass() = default; // If I omit this line I get an error
    myclass(int ID, double X, double Y, double Z): id(ID), x(X), y(Y), z(Z) {};
};
```

If I omit the line with the line `myclass() = default;` and then attempt at creating one object

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int ID = 0;
    double X = 1.0, Y = 2.0, Z = 3.0;
    vector<myclass> a_vector(10);

    myclass an_object(ID,X,Y,Z);

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error `no matching function for call to ‘myclass::myclass()`.

Why does this happen? When is it mandatory to specify the constructor taking no parameter as default?

This is probably a very easy question, but other questions on constructors seemed aimed at very specific issues with constructors, so I thought it might be worthwhile.

Comment: Have you  made them public: in your class?

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't require a default constructor, but then again, it's obvious this isn't the real code that produces the error message, because as shown above, your constructors are `private`.

Comment: Can you post the real code? Most likely, the issue has been obliterated by your removal of things like `public`.

Comment: No, if you write that `main()` function, then it will be accepted even without the default constructor (assuming you make the other constructor `public`). Post code that demonstrates the actual problem. Don't post some code that you think sort of looks something like it. If you've got it right, it takes just a single compiler invocation to verify that it's right.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it was a typo. The code is almost exactly like this (changed the names of the variable), except for the keyword `public'

Comment: Actually, also the vector was missing. Added it, now the code correctly produces the error. Apologies for the mistakes.

Comment: `vector<myclass> a_vector(10);` tries to default constructor 10 `myclass` instances, so it requires that the class be default constructible.

Comment: Note that specifying a constructor "as a default" doesn't mean that it's *the* default constructor, merely that its *implementation* is the default one with semantics mandated by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you provide any constructor(s), the compiler stops providing other ones for you - you become in full control. Thus when you have one that takes some parameters, the one that takes no parameters is not provided anymore.

Comment: Why is that absolutely necessary?

Comment: @ThreeDiag Because that's how C++ is designed. IOW, what other answer do you expect to that question? It's by design, what else is there to say...

Comment: To be clear though, the presence of a default constructor is absolutely not required unless you actually need the class to be default-constructible. The use of that class in the OP's `main()` function does not require any default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `vector` of `myclass` - `vector` has many methods that will use the default constructor. If you provide your own constructor as you did, the usual default constructor does *not* get generated for you. By adding the declaration with `= default`, you forced the compiler to generate the missing default. You could also define your own default constructor if the automatically generated one isn't sufficient, but there's no way to use a `vector` without one.

Answer (score 0):

because you didn't specify access modifiers for the second constructor, so it's private by default

simply add *public:* to your constructors

```
class myclass
{

int id;
double x, y, z;

public:

//myclass() = default; // If I omit this line I get an error
myclass(int ID, double X, double Y, double Z): id(ID), x(X), y(Y), z(Z) {};

};
```